# Spread an interleaved data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I have a `data.frame` which has an interleaved format, such that there are two groups (A and B), and each row of group B relates to the group A row immediately preceding it. For example:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(group = c("A","B","A","B","A","B","B","A","B"),
                 id = c("A.1","B.1","A.2","B.2","A.3","B.3.1","B.3.2","A.4","B.4"),
                 score = runif(9,0,1))
```

There cannot be consecutive rows of group A. In addition, in my real data there's no way to relate groups A and B other than that each group B rows are located immediately under the group A row they relate to.

I want to `spread` this `data.frame` to have these columns: idA, idB, scoreA, scoreB, such that a group A will repeat as many group B mappings i has in `df`.

So for this example the resulting `data.frame` is:

```
res.df <- data.frame(idA = c("A.1","A.2","A.3","A.3","A.4"),
                     idB = c("B.1","B.2","B.3.1","B.3.2","B.4"),
                     scoreA = df$score[c(1,3,5,5,8)],
                     scoreA = df$score[c(2,3,6,7,9)])
```

I imagine this can be easily done with `tidyr`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `sub_id` column that indicates whether the `A` group and `B` group should be aligned to the same row, separate the data frame into an A df and a B df, and then join the two sub data frames on the `sub_id` column:

```
df %>% 
    mutate(sub_id = cumsum(group == 'A')) %>% 
    {full_join(
        filter(., group == 'A') %>% select(-group), 
        filter(., group == 'B') %>% select(-group), 
        by = c('sub_id' = 'sub_id'), 
        suffix = c('A', 'B')
    )} %>% select(-sub_id)

#  idA    scoreA   idB    scoreB
#1 A.1 0.2655087   B.1 0.3721239
#2 A.2 0.5728534   B.2 0.9082078
#3 A.3 0.2016819 B.3.1 0.8983897
#4 A.3 0.2016819 B.3.2 0.9446753
#5 A.4 0.6607978   B.4 0.6291140
```

Or use `data.table::dcast` which supports pivoting multiple value columns:

```
library(data.table); library(zoo)    
dcast(
    setDT(df)[, 
# create a row number column that indicates which row the current row should go to
        rn := cumsum(!(group == 'B' & lag(group) == 'A'))
    ][], 
    rn ~ group, value.var = c('id', 'score')
)[, `:=` (
    id_A = na.locf(id_A), 
    score_A = na.locf(score_A), 
    rn = NULL
)][]

#   id_A  id_B   score_A   score_B
#1:  A.1   B.1 0.2655087 0.3721239
#2:  A.2   B.2 0.5728534 0.9082078
#3:  A.3 B.3.1 0.2016819 0.8983897
#4:  A.3 B.3.2 0.2016819 0.9446753
#5:  A.4   B.4 0.6607978 0.6291140
```